# Update and upgrade - review packages?

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, updates

Previously I have always run

```
apt-get update
```

and

```
apt-get upgrade
```

without thinking about it, without any problems to my knowledge. It occurred to me that this seems a bit gung-ho. How can you trust that their are not incompatibilities between OS and packages and packages and other packages? Should you just run it and trust assuming that all has been tested?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should - how else could you check for such possibilities?

`apt-get update` will update the repsitory data, both standard repositories and PPAs. With the updated information from the repositories, `apt-get upgrade` itself will review the package dependencies, and then inform you of any incompatibilities between packages in the main repositories or PPAs.

Comment: Wrong.  `apt-get update` will refresh ***all*** repository information, PPAs and standard system repositories alike.  `apt-get upgrade` and more simply, `apt-get` whenever you upgrade OR install, will handle dependency checks and such.

Comment: @ThomasW. My mistake - corrected my answer. Thnx for the info btw, I'd learned wrong information :(

Comment: @ThomasW. thnx for the edit

Comment: This does not, however, guarantee compatibility version-to-version of custom or third party packages inside themselves.  Keep that in mind.